# Can UIView be copied?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, copy

Simply using this way:

```
UIView* view2 = [view1 copy]; // view1 existed
```

This will cause simulator can not launch this app.

Try retain,

```
UIView* view2 = [view1 retain]; // view1 existed
// modify view2 frame etc
```

Any modifications to `view2` will apply to `view1`, I understand that `view2` share same memory with `view1`.

Why can't `UIView` be copied? What is the reason?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your app probably crashes with something like:

```
 [UIView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c6280
```

The reason is that UIView does not implement the copying protocol, and therefore there is no `copyWithZone` selector in UIView.

Comment: What should I do to implement the copy of UIView?

Comment: So if you have a certain combination of UIView and want to use that several time  you will need to subclass such UIView?

Comment: Yes, subclassing or category with class-level factory methods that return preconfigured instances of that view.

Answer (score 163):

this might work for you ... archive the view and then unarchive it right after.  This should give you a deep copy of a view:

```
id copyOfView = 
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:originalView]];
```

Comment: That seems like a bit of a hack but works like a dream. ssj's answer below is basically a 'copy constructor' which is fine for small classes. You can maybe use the obj-c runtime to copy all the properties at once.. This is still easier ;)

Comment: This sounds to good to be true. In my case it throws an NSInvalidArgumentException (`NSConcreteAttributedString initWithString:: nil value`) for a UILabel in the subview tree.

Comment: This works, but seems to be very slow for even trivial view trees.

Comment: It works, but beware! It does not set values for @IBOutlets, all of them are nil after "copying"

Comment: This seems to ignore `UIImageView`s :(

Comment: Thanks, works great! ALSO please note that the copied view has no superview (parent), no constraints and no gesture recognizers (if the parent had any).

Comment: agree with @IanNewson, just tried 2 approaches. A method, which:

1. instantiates new view and configure it
2. instantiates new view, configures it and archive. If archivation 

happened already, just call unarchiveObjectsWithData on saved data.

1. result of instantiation of 200 views, where this one is a subview ~ 0.5 sec.
2. result of instantiation of 200 views, where this one is a subview ~ 0.8 sec.
The view is only UIImageView with couple autoresizing masks.
I would not recommend archiving/unarchiving for duplication of views...

Comment: This throws a `value for key (UIHighlighted) is not a boolean` exception when using `UIImageView`s. You can use `let copyView = aView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)` instead.

Answer (score 27):

You can make an UIView extension. In example swift snippet below, function copyView returns an AnyObject so you could copy any subclass of an UIView, *ie* UIImageView. 
If you want to copy *only* UIViews you can change the return type to UIView.

```
//MARK: - UIView Extensions

    extension UIView
    {
       func copyView<T: UIView>() -> T {
            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)) as! T
       }
    }
```

Example usage:

```
let sourceView = UIView()
let copiedView = sourceView.copyView()
```

Comment: Thanks, works great! ALSO please note that the copied view has no superview (parent), no constraints and no gesture recognizers (if the parent had any).

Answer (score 7):

for swift3.0.1:

```
extension UIView{
 func copyView() -> AnyObject{
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self))! as AnyObject
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIView` doesn't implement the `NSCoping` protocol, see the declaration in *UIView.h*:

`@interface UIView : UIResponder <NSCoding, UIAppearance, UIAppearanceContainer, UIDynamicItem, UITraitEnvironment, UICoordinateSpace, UIFocusEnvironment>`

So, if we want to have a `copy` like method, we need to implement the `NSCoping` protocol in a category or so.

Answer (score -7):

You can make method something like this:

```
-(UILabel*)copyLabelFrom:(UILabel*)label{
//add whatever needs to be copied
UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:label.frame];
newLabel.backgroundColor = label.backgroundColor;
newLabel.textColor = label.textColor;
newLabel.textAlignment = label.textAlignment;
newLabel.text = label.text;
newLabel.font = label.font;

return [newLabel autorelease];

}
```

Then you can set your ivar to the return value and retain it like so:

```
myLabel = [[self copyLabelFrom:myOtherLabel] retain];
```

Comment: this isn't answering the question.

Comment: what if your label has other custom parameters like numberOfLines or tag? Will you set all properties?