# Add same subview multiple times to view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I don't know if this is possible, but what I would like to do is add a subview several times to the view. I have tried something like this:

```
[self.view addSubview: newView];
newView.center = CGPointMake(160, 100);
[self.view addSubview: newView];
newView.center = CGPointMake(160, 200);
[self.view addSubview: newView];
```

All this does is move `newView` around, without adding new ones. Any ideas?

I also tried this:

```
[self.view addSubview:newView];
UIView *anotherView = newView;
anotherView.center = CGPointMake(160, 100)
[self.view addSubview:anotherView];
```

**Edit**

**Here's a solution I've learned with time**

Another way to solve the problem would be to make a separate nib containing the view and add instances of the nib several times. A good template to work off to implement this solution is to do it the same way a custom `UITableViewCell` is used in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Thanks for posing this question. This indirectly answered one of mine! Time saved! WOOHOO!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A view can only be contained in a single parent view's hierarchy. As soon as you add it to a new one, it is removed from the previous one. In this case, it is being removed and added back to the same view's hierarchy. You would need to make a copy of the sub-view to have it appear multiple times.

Comment: You are just creating a new pointer to the same UIView object. Since UIViews do not respond to copy, you will need to actually allocate and init a new UIView and customize it to match the first one. This may help in that regard: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425939/uiview-can-not-be-copy.