# How to create a copy of uiview (not a pointer to original uiview)

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiview, nscopying

I want to create a copy of a `UIView`, and I dont want to use `NSKeyedArchiver` because I am frequently creating a copy of many views, and using `NSKeyedArchiver` was slow.

I heard about `copy` or `initWithZone:`, but Googling it found it is not good for `UIView`.  I don't want a copy which points to the original view because any changes made to it will also make changes to the copied `UIView`.

Comment: You cannot copy a view. If you want a "copy" you either have to do a deep copy with NSCoding (the keyed archiver stuff) or you have to implement some copiable data object that your view uses to set itself up and updates, then copy that out of one stock view and add it to another. But there's no way to just "copy" a view.

Comment: Wait, when you say that you want a copy that points to the original do you mean that you want the same view in 2 different places?

Comment: i just wanted to save the state of a uiview at a particular moment to another uiview because i have implemented rotation,scaling and movement of uiviews with touch.

So can you plz tell me how to copy the properties of a uiview to other if it cant be copied..thnx

Comment: No i dont waqnt the copied uiview to point to the original one...i want it to be cloned

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425939/can-uiview-be-copied

Comment: To copy it you'd have to implement a "deep copy", since with any not-trivial view the real stuff is the embedded views.  But if you just want to "save the state" of the view you might be able to do that by recording the frame of the view and its component views, and whatever other parameters are of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy a view using:

```
TheView *copyOfView =  (TheView *) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:origionalTheView]];
```

Answer (score -4):

Create a UIView Category which can help in copying the view. Something like this:

```
- (id) copyView {
     UIView *a = [[UIView alloc]init];
     a.frame = self.frame;
     //set all other properties of the UIView
     return a; //return [a autorelease] if not using ARC
}
```

Comment: this will not copy all atributes of the desired view