# Cannot change tuple in an array

Tags: swift

I'm trying to change a tuple in an array , however ,when I try 
`emo = (type:emo.type,strength:increaseStrength(emo.strength))`
it gives me error

`"cannot assign to 'let' value 'emo'`

here is my code :

```
var emotions : [(type : String, strength: Int)] = [("happy",0),("scared",0),("tender",0),("excited",0),("sad",0)]

func increaseStrength(i:Int)->Int {
    switch i {
    case 0: return 1
    case 1: return 2
    case 2: return 3
    case 3: return 0
    default :return 0
    }
}

@IBAction func HappyBA(sender: AnyObject) {
    for emo in emotions  {
        if (emo.type == "happy" ){
            emo = (type:emo.type,strength:increaseStrength(emo.strength))

        }
    }
    println(emotions)
}
```

If there are better way to do the assignment please tell me I am so appreciated ! Thanks..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no point assigning to `emo` even if you could do it. This is not the same as replacing the corresponding object in the array - which is what you *do* want to do. `emo` is a *copy*; even if you were to set a property of it, it wouldn't affect the one back in the array. And certainly setting the *variable* would not magically read back into the array!

Here's one solution. Instead of cycling thru `emotions` in your for-loop, cycle thru `enumerate(emotions)`. Now you have a tuple of an index number along with an emotion. If this is the right emotion type, write into the array via the index number.

```
for (ix,emo) in enumerate(emotions) {
    if emo.type == "happy" {
        emotions[ix] = (type:emo.type,strength:increaseStrength(emo.strength))
    }
}
```

Or you could use `map`.

```
emotions = emotions.map  {
    emo in
    if emo.type == "happy" {
        return (type:emo.type,strength:increaseStrength(emo.strength))
    } else {
        return emo
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt ,Thanks for your detailed answer and teaching me how to use map, my best wishes!

Comment: Btw @matt, I am glad I've viewed your book previously ,you are an awesome writer , will buy your newest book once you released .

Comment: @Yank Glad to help! Personally I like `map` better. In this case it's more lines of code, but it describes so clearly what you are going to do to your array.

Comment: it's my pleasure to have your answer, I like map as well, I did computing science grade in uni , map is more reasonable and make the code looks more professional XD

Comment: `emo` is a copy because it's a tuple, correct? If it were an object, editing `emo` inside the loop would work?

Comment: @Crashalot Might help you to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27366050/341994

Comment: @matt Thanks, very helpful! Do you happen to know this answer on property observers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586564/swift-use-property-observers-while-defining-variables-one-per-line. Thanks again.

Comment: @Crashalot I don't know what a "property observer" is. Do you mean setter observer?

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize it was a standard term, meant this: http://www.codingexplorer.com/swift-property-observers/