# Swift: use property observers while defining variables one per line

Tags: swift

The problem with property observers in Swift is they disperse variables across the class, making it harder to see and understand the properties used.

Without property observers, you can list all variables and default values in a singe block, one per line, so it's much easier to see the class properties.

For instance, without property observers:

```
class User: NSObject, NSCoding {
    // NSCoding Keys
    static let UserKey = "UserKey"
    let Key1 = "Key1"
    let Key2 = "Key2"
    let Key3 = "Key3"

    // Constants
    let Constant1 = "Constant1"
    let Constant2 = "Constant2"
    let Constant3 = "Constant3"

    // Stat Vars
    var var1 = 0
    var var2 = 0
    var var3 = 0

    // Logging Vars
    var lvar1 = 0
    var lvar2 = 0
    var lvar3 = 0

    // Misc Vars
    var mvar1 = 0
    var mvar2 = 0
    var mvar3 = 0
}
```

Is there a way to organize properties like this, that is one per line, while also using property observers to act as setters/getters? Essentially, the goal is to define properties in one section, and where setter/getter functionality is needed, define that elsewhere in the file.

The assumption is no, but hopefully someone has a clever suggestion.

Comment: You can't have a setter observer on a `let` property in any case.

Comment: Correct, the question was implicitly asking about setters for mutable properties. The `let` properties should have been removed for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Note: There's no such thing as "property observer". Swift variables — not just properties, but *any* variable — can have setter observers (`willSet` and `didSet`). You can't observe the getting of a stored variable. Also, you can't have a setter observer on a `let` variable, because (wait for it) it can't be set. My answer is thus based on mentally changing your question to fit those facts. Even so, I don't really see what the question is, because I do not see in what sense setter observers "disperse variables across the class". However...]

A variable's setter observer is part of the variable declaration. It can't be appended later. The closest you can come to appending a setter observer separately from the variable declaration is to subclass (though this, it seem to me, would be a very silly and confusing thing to do gratuitously):

```
class User {
    var (var1, var2, var3) = (0,0,0) // super neatness
}
class MyUser:User { // add setter observers
    override var var1 : Int {
        didSet {}
        willSet {}
    }
    override var var2 : Int {
        didSet {}
        willSet {}
    }
    override var var3 : Int {
        didSet {}
        willSet {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is as feared. "Dispersed" means property declarations span multiple lines instead of one line, making them harder to see and causing classes to mix setter/getter functionality with property declarations instead of grouping property declarations in one area and setter/getters in another discrete section.

Comment: You keep saying setter/getter but there are no getter observers and a setter observer is not where the setter _functionality_ is. Did you want a computed property?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this. The confusion stems from a section in the Apple docs, which says: "Property observers observe and respond to changes in a property’s value. Property observers are called every time a property’s value is set, even if the new value is the same as the property’s current value." Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

Comment: Dispersing is "grouping property declarations in one area and setter/getter in another discrete section". That is dispersing. Keeping everything local at the declaration site decreases the chance of unexpected side effects. It increases knowledge about the property and how it is used. Make your coding decisions based on what is most maintainable.

Comment: @Crashalot "Property observer" was a poor choice of term on Apple's part, since this has nothing to do with properties except incidentally. `willSet` and `didSet` functions may be attached to _any_ variable, not merely variables declared at the top level of an object type declaration (which is what a property is). I suppose that in practice you are in fact most likely to implement setter observers for a property, but that's a tactical decision, not a syntactical limitation. :)