# What are the rules for tuple mutability?

Tags: swift, tuples, immutability

By trial&error I found some facts about tuples and mutability in Swift, but would like to learn about actual rules. Consider such code:

```
class T
{
    var f : String = "hello"
}

let a = T();
let b = (f : "hello", "");
a.f = "world";
b.f = "world";
println(a.f)
println(b.f)
```

`a` behaves like fixed reference (you can change any member you like of the object, just not the main reference). So it is like `readonly` in C#.

But `b` behaves more like constant value -- the above code does not compile. One could say that `let` (or `var`) is applied to all the members of the tuple.

But it is guessing from my part -- so back to my question. What are the rules for tuples and their mutability?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Swift Pass By Value or Pass By Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364117/is-swift-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference)

Comment: @matt, to make a real answer to my question I would have to know if tuple is defined as value type (`struct`) or reference one (`class`), but this info I also cannot find.

Comment: @greenoldman as stated in the Swift guide, tuples are compound data types. Therefore, defining it as `let` makes it and its "members" immutable.

Comment: But the other question's answer answers that. Everything except class instance or function is a value type. Tuple is not class instance or function. Can you do the logic?

Comment: @matt, and how do I know if `tuple` is not defined as `class` internally?

Comment: @SebastianDressler, thank you. Could you post is as regular answer so I could accept it? Now, knowing what to look for I found how Swift differentiates types -- to named and compound ones.

Comment: @greenoldman It's just like how you know that struct is not defined as class internally, or how you know that tiger is not defined as hollyhock internally. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [The Swift Programming Language: The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309), tuples are compound types in Swift. Therefore, if one creates a constant variable with `let` which has a tuple as type, all values in the tuple become constant too.