# Swift AnyClass reference to Class instance or just Type?

Tags: swift

In the example below is `stateClass: AnyClass`an actual instance of a class that for example I could then call to get `stateClass.name` or is it simply a reference to the class type. My feeling is that from the `validChange` line that its just a reference to Class Type not an actual instance of any class that I can pull data out of?

```
override func isValidNextState(stateClass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
    let validChange = stateClass is MonsterAttack.Type
    return validChange
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`AnyClass` is defined as followed: `typealias AnyClass = AnyObject.Type` which is the actual class type itself. So if you have a `class` with name "Test" you have to pass `Test.self` and you can only call static/class methods/properties and initializers on it. If you want to use the actual instance use `AnyObject` (only for classes) or `Any`(for anything):

```
override func isValidNextState(stateClass: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    let validChange = stateClass is MonsterAttack.Type
    return validChange
}
```

Comment: If you want to access the instance of that class you can do

     `stateMachine!.stateForClass(stateClass)`

Comment: @sez What type has `stateMachine`?

Comment: It's a `GKStateMachine`.  Note that it will return `nil` if the state has been constructed but not added to a state machine yet.  But since `isValidNextState` is called by the state machine that owns that state it should be fine to call `stateForClass` inside `isValidNextState`.

Answer (score 1):

It is simply a reference to the class type, ie you could call:

```
isValidNextState(SomeClass.self)
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes are reference types. So when you pass stateClass, you're simply passing the pointer to the stateClass instance of `MonsterAttack`. So stateClass is an instance yes, but it is the *same* instance to the one that you passed into your `isValidNextState` function

The `let validChange` appears be just optionally casting the argument into a `MonsterAttack` type.

This answer may help further: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366050/4396258