# Why can I manipulate a UIView's properties in Swift by passing it into a function if Swift passes by value not reference?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, reference, pass-by-reference

Perhaps this is a silly question and I'm completely misunderstanding how passing variable in Swift works, but I was under the impression that Swift was pass by copy by default, and you could use the `inout` keyword to denote passing by reference.

How come then, if I have a function that has a `UIView` parameter, I can change, say, the `backgroundColor` of the `UIView` within that function, and it's reflected outside the function. If the function creates a local copy when passed, how is this affecting the passed variable?

Why does that not require inout?

Comment: Short: UIView is a reference type (as are all classes).

Answer (score 1):

Because the `UIView` you pass around is a class instance: it is a pointer to begin with. So, in essence, you *are* passing that pointer by value, since you are not passing a *reference* to that pointer (like `&pointer` in **C**).

See [Is Swift Pass By Value or Pass By Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364117/is-swift-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference) for an elaborate answer.