# How to keep the reference to an array after manipulation?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How do I keep the reference to an array after an items is appended?

**Updated code example**, because the prior example didn't seem to be clear enough.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var numbers = Numbers.singleton.numbers

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        print(numbers.count)

        Numbers.singleton.add(1)

        print(numbers.count) // prints 0
        print(Numbers.singleton.numbers.count) // prints 1
    }
}

class Numbers {

    static let singleton = Numbers()

    var numbers: [Int]!

    private init() {
        numbers = []
    }

    func add(number: Int) {
        numbers.append(number)
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you switched the outputs - the first print prints 1, the second one 0.

Comment: @luk2302 Whoops, I did!

Comment: What's the problem? You changed `self.array` and it worked. Your `arrayRef` is a pointless copy; just delete it from the story.

Comment: What is the reason of creating a reference to an array? And, can you change the type of array (to NSArray)?

Comment: @matt But how can I reference to the array? I want to reference to the array from outside the class. The above is just an example to demonstrate it.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10 - *"In Swift, `Array`, `String`, and `Dictionary` are all value types."*

Comment: But that isn't at all what you asked. To refer to the array from outside the class, get a reference to this view controller and talk of `theViewController.array`. It is a public property.

Comment: @matt Thanks, the construct is more complicated for the simple question. I just wanted to understand why I cannot reference to it. Now it makes sense since it is a value type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in Swift don't have "references". They are structs, and a struct is a [value type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366050/341994). Your (badly named) `arrayRef` is a separate *copy*, not a reference to `self.array`.

Moreover, there is no good reason to want to do what you (seem to) want to do. To have two simultaneous references to a mutable array would be unsafe, since the array can be changed behind your back. The Swift design is sensible; use it, don't subvert it.

Comment: So if I use NSArray instead I could reference to it, since it is a class?

Comment: Certainly. But you still couldn't _change_ the array (append to it) through NSArray, as NSArray is immutable. That is how Cocoa provides the same kind of safety that Swift does.

Comment: So I updated the code example to closer resemble the actual code. The `numbers` array can indeed be changed by other processes in the app. The reference to the array is defined as a property with `var numbers = Numbers.singleton.numbers` to be available throughout the class. But that is actually copying the array as I understand. So what would be a good design for this - only access it through with `Numbers.singleton.numbers` throughout the class?

Comment: I still don't know what you are trying to do (or what you think you are trying to do). What are your goals for being able to access / change this array?

Comment: The `numbers` array contains data points that are collected over time.  To make the data points available throughout the app they are stored in a singleton class. The adding of data points happens by another process in the app which also triggers a NSNotification for all observers of the data points. When a new data point is added the control to display the data points should reload it's data source, i.e. the `numbers` array. So to handle the notification I should update the data source by copying the array from the singleton class as I understood from your explanation.

Comment: You don't need to "copy" anything. Your array is a publicly visible `var` property; anyone can `append` to it. Again I ask, what's the problem?

Comment: Thanks matt. My original question is already answered because I didn't know that an array was a value type and that caused the behaviour I didn't understand.