# Using a Swift struct in an NSOutlineView

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm trying to populate an `NSOutlineView` with Swift structs as its items. This works, except for the `row(forItem:)` method, which always returns -1.
I've made sure my struct conforms to `Equatable` and I implemented an `isEqual` function. Still the `NSOutlineView` can not find the row for any item.

If I convert my struct to a class (*not* derived from NSObject), it all works. Even without conforming to `Equatable` or implementing any `isEqual` functions.

I thought classes and structs in Swift are basically the same except one being a reference type and the other a value type.

What do I need to implement to use Swift structs as items in an `NSOutlineView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone posted [a similar question](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/68477) on the Apple Developer Forum.

NSOutlineView doesn't use Equatable when identifying an item, it uses the reference pointer to the item. In Swift, structs are always passed by value (and not passed by reference) so the outline view will never recognize that the item you're passing is the same. Switching your struct to a class fixes the issue because Swift uses pass by reference for classes.

Unfortunately, there's no way to use Structs as items to work with NSOutlineView and you will need to use a Class.

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366050/4133371) for more details about how Swift uses pass by reference vs. pass by value.

Comment: It’s a bi pt of a trap. It’ll work at first because if you import Foundation, structure can be automatically packed into `_SwiftValue`. You’ll get subtle bugs though, since those boxes will be created at different times, and they won’t have a stable reference identity, which is what `NSOutlineView` was relying on

Answer (score 3):

Release notes for macOS 10.14 point that if a Swift value type conforms to both Equatable and Hashable protocols, the NSOutlineView will successfully work with that value type.

But if you build against an older SDK, the value types won't work with the NSOutlineView indeed.

Comment: Link to the AppKit release notes: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos_release_notes/macos_mojave_10_14_release_notes/appkit_release_notes_for_macos_10_14

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a never-ending question, I will add more information about the determination between structures and classes for the NSOutlineView data source.

If you have no time to finish the reading, you can populate NSOutlineView with the values from structures or classes. You choose.

## The Model

You always use the data model for the data storage and fetch. The best practice is to hide the model behind the model controller. Since then, your OutlineView will never actually view the data source.

The Data Source Delegate.

The control uses a delegator to fill the fields. Since then, you will scan the model for the values. You can fill the control with the references to the class members and the structure values. There is no feedback from the control on the data. The control itself never changes the data directly.
If you change the values in the model, the control will not react to such a change whenever it is a class or structure. It needs to be reloaded to reflect the change. During the reloading procedure, the control replaces all the data. It does not observe data or pool the values over the `didSet` methods to the class properties.

## Drag-and-Drop

If you implement the drag-and-drop functionality in your control, you'll face the value transfer problem. The drag-and-drop technology in the outline and table views is based on a pasteboard concept.
Even if you are working with the classes as the data source, you will copy the class instance at the moment of drag start and immediately lose any hard reference to the source. You will implement some ID properties for the outline view entry to fix this. It will destroy the class-based data source's purity and implicitly convert the class-based data to structure-based data or a kind of hybrid one.

## Data update from the control

If the control updates the data, which is possible, then it has to use some kind of NSTextFields as views or cells. The subclassed text field cannot change the data but can store ID (Struct) or references (Class) to the model's records. It fires the `@objc func` on text update, and then the update may hit the model controller if you'd like. As I said above, the model controller loops the data and naturally matches the data source by reference to the ID.

Answer (score -1):

You may override the method `row(forItem item: Any?)` in your subclass by simply looking all rows and returning the index of the equal ones.