# Swift How to for-in loop over references

Tags: swift, for-loop, pass-by-reference

I have quite a few similar `UILabels` I setup in code. 
In Objective-C I would do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *l1, *l2, *l3, *l4, *l5, *l6, *l7, *l8, *l9;
...
l1 = [[UILabel alloc] init]; 
l2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
l3 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
...
NSArray *lbls = @[l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9];
for(UILabel *l in lbls) {
   l.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
   l.hidden = YES;
   ...
   [self.addSubview:l];
}
```

How would I do this in Swift? How can I pass the reference to a variable in a `for in` loop?
The only option I found was to make a function with an `inout` parameter, but that splits my code into different areas.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have 10 label variables instead of one array variable in the first places?

Comment: fair point ;-) am going to implement something like vacawama suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it in Swift exactly the same way you do it in Objective-C:

```
let lbls = [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9]
for l in lbls {
   l.textColor = .red
   l.isHidden = true
   self.addSubview(l)
}
```

This works the same way it did in Objective-C because UILabel is a class, which is a *[reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366050/341994)*. This means that, in a very real sense, `l` is a pointer every bit as much in Swift as in Objective-C (where the pointer-ness is made explicit by the `UILabel*` syntax).

---

**Extra Credit**

On the other hand, as long as you didn't intend to write all those changes back into `lbls`, you could also make this work even if this were a value type. You would have to assign `l` into a `var` inside the loop in order to change it.

So, let's suppose for purposes of illustration that we have a *struct* here. Then you would say:

```
let myArrayOfStructs = [l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, l6, l7, l8, l9]
for s in myArrayOfStructs {
   var s = s // make a version of `s` we can modify
   s.someProperty = newValue
   self.someMethod(s)
}
```

But, as I say, this would *not* write back the changes into the contents of the original array. Still, if your only purpose is to configure each `s` and then hand it off to some other method, you might not care about that.

Comment: I wish extra credit could be given. This two variation answer deserves it. THANK YOU!

Comment: Note you can also say `for var s in myArrayOfStructs {...}`

Comment: @Hamish Yes, I became shy of that syntax because for a while they threatened to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

It can be pretty much exactly the same.

I would do it this way...

```
labels.forEach {
    $0.backgroundColor = .red
    view.addSubview($0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why have 9 different variables to hold the labels?  You can start with all of them in an array and refer to them as `labels[0]`, `labels[1]`, `...` , `labels[8]` when you need to access them individually:

```
// Create 9 UILabels and store them in [UILabel]
var labels = (1...9).map { _ in UILabel() }
```

...

```
for l in labels {
    l.textColor = .red
    l.isHidden = true
    self.addSubview(l)
}
```

Comment: good point. where as matt's answer answers my original question - I will go forward with this solution. +1