# Assigning a reference from a class member to variable in Swift

Tags: swift, class, reference, var

```
class UserDataStore {
}

class ProfileInteractor {

    var userDataStore: UserDataStore?

    init(userDataStore: UserDataStore?) {
        self.userDataStore = userDataStore
    }
}

var profileInteractor = ProfileInteractor(userDataStore: UserDataStore())
var userDataStore = profileInteractor.userDataStore
profileInteractor.userDataStore = nil

print(profileInteractor.userDataStore == nil) // prints: true
print(userDataStore == nil) // prints: false
print(userDataStore === profileInteractor.userDataStore) // prints: false
```

- Can anyone please explain, why userDataStore doesn't point to profileInteractor.userDataStore !?
- What must I do, that userDataStore points to it?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364117/is-swift-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why userDataStore doesn't point to profileInteractor.userDataStore !?

In this line:

```
var profileInteractor = ProfileInteractor(userDataStore: UserDataStore())
```

You created a new `ProfileInteractor` object and a new `UserDataStore` object. Then, you made `profileInteractor` refer to the `ProfileInteractor` object.

In the next line:

```
var userDataStore = profileInteractor.userDataStore
```

You are making `userDataStore` refer to the same object as `profileInteractor.userDataStore`. Now anything you do to the `UserDataStore` object by using `userDataStore` will be reflected on `profileInteractor.userDataStore` because they are essentially the same thing.

However, this line changes everything:

```
profileInteractor.userDataStore = nil
```

You made `profileInteractor.userDataStore` refer to nothing. This *DOES NOT* mean that the `UserDataStore` object is destroyed. This just means that you no longer can use `profileInteractor.userDataStore` to access the `UserDataStore` object. But guess what is still referring to the `UserDataStore` object? `userDataStore`!

So the answer to your question is that `userDataStore` did point to the same object as `profileInteractor.userDataStore`, until you set `profileInteractor.userDataStore` to nil.

> What must I do, that userDataStore points to it?

Well, you already did. You just made `profileInteractor.userDataStore` point to *something else* in the next line of code.

If you want a local variable to always point to the same thing that another local variable points to, your code can get quite messy, like in Ankit Thakur's answer, with unsafe pointers and stuff. If you are passing the variable to a method, you can use the `inout` keyword.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, that I saw this, I thought, this is exactly like ARC works ^^

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are *misunderstanding* the purpose of assigning `nil` to `userDataStore`.

Assigning `userDataStore` to `nil` means that it will not point to anything, i.e it will be destroyed; That should *not* leads to let `profileInteractor.userDataStore` to be also `nil`. `nil` in Swift means that there is nothing at all, it does `not` mean that it is a pointer to an empty space in the memory.

To make it more clear, check the following code snippet:

```
class UserDataStore: CustomStringConvertible {
    var title: String?

    var description: String {
        return "\(title)"
    }

    init(_ title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

class ProfileInteractor {

    var userDataStore: UserDataStore?

    init(userDataStore: UserDataStore?) {
        self.userDataStore = userDataStore
    }
}

var profileInteractor = ProfileInteractor(userDataStore: UserDataStore("Hello"))
var userDataStore = profileInteractor.userDataStore

print(userDataStore === profileInteractor.userDataStore) // prints: true
print(profileInteractor.userDataStore) // prints: Optional(Optional("Hello"))

userDataStore?.title = "Bye"

print(profileInteractor.userDataStore) // prints: Optional(Optional("Bye"))

userDataStore = nil

print(profileInteractor.userDataStore) // prints: Optional(Optional("Bye"))
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Copying a reference, implicitly creates a shared instance. After a copy, two variables then refer to a single instance of the data, so modifying data in the second variable also affects the original

```
class UserDataStore {
    var inst:String?


    init(obj: String?) {
        self.inst = obj
    }

}

class ProfileInteractor {

    var userDataStore: UserDataStore?

    init(userDataStore: UserDataStore?) {
        self.userDataStore = userDataStore
    }
}

var profileInteractor = ProfileInteractor(userDataStore: UserDataStore(obj: "10"))
var userDataStore = profileInteractor.userDataStore

withUnsafePointer(to: &(profileInteractor.userDataStore)) {
    print(" profileInteractor.userDataStore has address: \($0)")
}
withUnsafePointer(to: &userDataStore) {
    print("userDataStore has address: \($0)")
}

withUnsafePointer(to: &(((profileInteractor.userDataStore) as! UserDataStore).inst)) {
    print(" profileInteractor.userDataStore value inst has address: \($0)")
}
withUnsafePointer(to: &(((userDataStore) as! UserDataStore).inst)) {
    print("userDataStore value inst has address: \($0)")
}

print(userDataStore)
print(profileInteractor.userDataStore)

profileInteractor.userDataStore = nil

print(profileInteractor.userDataStore == nil) // prints: true
print(userDataStore == nil) // prints: false

print(userDataStore === profileInteractor.userDataStore) // prints: false
```

Output:

```
 profileInteractor.userDataStore has address: 0x0000610000031230
userDataStore has address: 0x000000010e8103e0
 profileInteractor.userDataStore value inst has address: 0x000061000004f5b0
userDataStore value inst has address: 0x000061000004f5b0
Optional(__lldb_expr_35.UserDataStore)
Optional(__lldb_expr_35.UserDataStore)
true
false
false
```

Here is the nice reference of pass by value and pass by reference:
https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10