# Swift 4 Mutable Collection of Mutable Objects?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, collections, sprite-kit

I want to create a pool of sprites that I can move around on the screen without having to reinitialize and add them to my scene over and over.

To do this, I want to store a collection of objects in a way that I can easily access and mutate the objects.

My initial thought was to use an Array, but it appears Swift passes back a copy of an object when I reference the array.

```
var nodes:[SKNodes] = SKNodes();
nodes.append(SKNode());

nodes[0].position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100) //doesn't work
```

What is the best practice for creating something like this?

**EDIT:**

It wasn't working due to a typo, silly me. For some reason I thought it wasn't working because Swift would pass by value, and I would get a copy of the object in the array instead of a reference to the object.

I have now learned that Swift passes Objects and Functions as a Reference Type, and basically only structs and enums are pass by value

[Is Swift Pass By Value or Pass By Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364117/is-swift-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference)

```
var nodes:[SKNode] = SKNodes();
nodes.append(SKNode());

nodes[0].position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100) //Works!
```

Comment: Did you forget to add the nodes in the array to the scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you append `SKNode` to the `Array`, it should be `[SKNode]` instead of `[SKNodes]`

```
var nodes:[SKNode] = SKNodes();
nodes.append(SKNode());
nodes[0].position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100) //should work
```