# Can't change String Array in Swift 2 after returning it from function

Tags: swift

**I have this playground example:**

```
import UIKit

var testArray: [[String]] = [["2","2"],["1","1"]]

testArray[0][0] = "3" // Working

func getTestArray() -> [String] {

    return testArray[0]

}

var test = getTestArray()[0] = "4" // Error: Immutable Value
```

How can i get the reference of testArray to change it

**Changing test won't change testArray!**

Comment: Swift arrays are *value types.* Your function returns a *value,* not a reference to the original array.

Comment: How can i return the reference then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364117/is-swift-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference

Comment: Kind of irrelevant, but why are you (still) in Swift 2?

Comment: @Sweeper it's for a project that uses an outdated sdk and sadly can't be updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getTestArray()` returns a **value**, not a **reference**. Therefore, the value returned by a function cannot be edited, only **variables** can be changed. To change the variable, use:

```
var testVal = getTestArray() // get the value
testVal[0] = "4" // change the value
testArray[0] = testVal // SET the value of the reference `testArray` (change the value)
```

Comment: With this solution getTestArray() would be useless. You could get testArray directly. But maybe there is no better solution

Comment: @JonasSchafft To be honest, why you need such a function?

Comment: Difficult to explain. But it would help me in an specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign value to `test` and than change it:

```
var test = getTestArray()
test[0] = "4"
```

Comment: Then i`m not changing testArray

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = getTestArray()
test[0] = "4"
print(test)
```

Comment: Then i`m not changing testArray

Comment: I need to change testArray. Not something else. Can i get the reference?

Comment: They are not reference types

Comment: use classes instead