# How to copy a class to be independent of its parent in Xcode Swift 4

Tags: swift, class

I'm stumped about this one: I have a custom class called CClass. Within this class is a counter called counter. 
I initialize my instances as follows.

```
var ArrayEntity = [CClass]()
var ParentOne = CClass()
var ParentTwo = CClass()
```

Later, I assign each Parent to one of the Array entities, like so:

```
ParentOne = ArrayEntity[i]
ParentTwo = ArrayEntity[i]
```

Sometimes i will be the same value for both, and thus both will refer to the same Array instance. 
The trouble is that if I do something like this:

```
ParentOne.counter = 1
//value of ParentTwo.counter also becomes 1
//ArrayEntity[i].counter also becomes 1
```

I wish to have these Parent guys be independent of the ArrayEntity entries they are cloned from, but how do I do this?

Thanks much for any insight. Hopefully it's just a stupid oversight!

Comment: Sorry, initial post was not clear enough. Effectively yes: counter (and the class as a whole) is a copy of another instance.

Comment: Use a `struct` instead of `class`. What you are seeing is normal for classes when two variables point to the same reference.

Comment: As I'm over 2,000 lines deep into the code, and the whole thing depends on this class, might I do something like copy the individual portions of the class over? Like do this instead: ParentOne.counter = ArrayEntry[i].counter? Will that keep things separate or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how classes work. Assignment does not copy the object; it merely creates multiple references to the same object. Consider:

```
class Dog {
    var name : String = "Fido"
}
var fido = Dog()
print(fido.name) // Fido
var rover = fido
rover.name = "Rover"
print(fido.name) // Rover
```

In that code, we changed the `name` property of `rover`, a class instance — and the `name` property of `fido` was changed as well! That’s because, after the assignment in the third line, `fido` and `rover` refer to *one and the same instance.*

If you don't want that sort of thing to happen, don't maintain two references to one and the same instance. A possible strategy here might be give Dog an `init(dog:)` method that makes a *new* Dog that starts out life with the same property values as the original — a clone, as it were. Now you've got two separate objects that can proceed to live independent lives.

Comment: Structs, however, do not behave in that way. With a struct, assignment _does_ copy. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364117/is-swift-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference/27366050#27366050

Comment: Wow, thank you! Very informative stuff! It appears if I copy over just the individual parts of the class, I can get away with it, but in future I should definitely be using a struct for this rather than a class.

Comment: You can "get away with it" as long as the parts _themselves_ are not classes. If they are, you'll get the same issue one level down. :)