# Variable value of a ViewController is changed by forward ViewController when passed parameter

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

My question is a bit confused.
I've a ViewController that shows to the user some attributes, these attributes are in a dictionary. For edit these attributes I've another ViewController, that when I "segue" to that I pass the attributes in the default way, like this:

```
viewController.value = self.value
```

On the second ViewController (view controller of edition) I've options to Back to ViewController and Save the changes, so, I can change values without save or save. When I change values and not save, just back to view controller, the value is changed in the previous view controller. I don't understannd how this happens. I will try show with images.

My first view controller is: ViewContollerSale.swift

My second (edit) view controller is: ViewControllerCreateSale.swift

ViewControllerSale.swift

```
var saleOrder : SaleOrder?  // at this point it's populated


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("===> VcSale: prepare")
    if segue.identifier == "segueEditOrder" {
        print("segue: segueEditOrder")
        let editVc = segue.destination as! ViewControllerCreateSale
        editVc.saleToEdit = true
        if saleOrder != nil {
            editVc.sale = saleOrder!
        }
    }
}
```

ViewControllerCreateSale.swift

The function that set value is showed below. But I think that this changes only value of instance context of ViewControllerCreateSale.swift, but when I back view controller the value is changed also on the previous view controller!

```
var sale: SaleOrder = SaleOrder()

case Notification.Name.opEntrega:
    aux = notf.object as! String
    sale.attributes["delivery_term_id"] = aux == "CIF" ? Int32(1) : Int32(2)
    let cell = tableOptionsSelect.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)) as! CellSelectionCreateSale
    cell.lblOptionSelect.text = aux
    break
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a SaleOrder to the second view controller you are passing a reference to the SaleOrder instead of a copy.

That means whenever you update the SaleOrder on the second screen you are updating the same SaleOrder used by the first one.

I think simply changing it to let instead of var in the first screen might fix it.
You can also try passing a copy of the object instead of a reference with saleOrder!.copy(), though I think your SaleOrder class will need to conform to the NSCopying protocol.

If you want to learn more about reference types you can read this topic [Is Swift Pass By Value or Pass By Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364117/is-swift-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference)

Comment: I didn't know that Swift does it. Thank you.