# Inout on Swift class method

Tags: swift3

In this excerpt from Big Nerd Ranch Chapter 24, why does takeOwnership() not need to use an inout parameter when it is making a change to asset?
Since it is modifying the asset's owner, I would have expected asset to be in-out.

Thank you in advance!

```
class Person {
var assets = [Asset]()

init(name: String) {
    self.name = name
}

func takeOwnership(of asset: Asset) {
    asset.owner = self
    assets.append(asset)
}
```

}

Comment: Because Asset is a class, a reference type. It is therefore mutable in place and what is passed is a pointer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364117/is-swift-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference and also http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECreferenceTypes

Answer (score 0):

`Asset` is a class, so it's passed in by reference. Changes made to the `asset` argument are changes to the object being passed in. If `Asset` were a struct, it would indeed have to be an inout argument.

[Checkout this doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html)

Comment: Thank you! So the argument itself is constant, and it is an object pointer. Changes to the object it is pointing to are acceptable, but changes to the pointer itself would not be. Is that correct? (I'm more familiar with Java so using the pointer analogy here).

Comment: No problem! Yep, I think the pointer analogy works. Mostly the thing to know is that classes are passed around by reference (pointer) and struts are passed around by value

Comment: @JonLee If you have any other questions, I'd be happy to elaborate. Otherwise mark this as the answer if you feel it properly answers the question. Thanks!