# Changing value of a struct has no effect

Tags: ios, swift, swift-structs

I have UICollectionView that have a model with following:

```
class MainVCModel {

    let models = [
        CellModel.init(UIImage.init(named: "1.jpg")!),
        CellModel.init(UIImage.init(named: "2.jpg")!),
        CellModel.init(UIImage.init(named: "3.jpg")!),
        CellModel.init(UIImage.init(named: "4.jpg")!),
        CellModel.init(UIImage.init(named: "5.jpg")!),
        CellModel.init(UIImage.init(named: "6.jpg")!),
        CellModel.init(UIImage.init(named: "7.jpg")!),
        CellModel.init(UIImage.init(named: "8.jpg")!),
        CellModel.init(UIImage.init(named: "9.jpg")!),
    ]
}

struct CellModel {
    var isEnlarged: Bool = false
    var image: UIImage

    lazy var rotatedImage: UIImage = self.image.rotate(radians: Float(Helper.degreesToRadians(degrees: 6)))!

    init(_ image: UIImage){
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

In my CollectionViewController class i have:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var currentModel = model.models[indexPath.row]
        if !currentModel.isEnlarged {
            print("should enlarge")
            currentModel.isEnlarged = true
            enlargeOnSelection(indexPath)
        }   else {
            print("should restore")
            currentModel.isEnlarged = false
            restoreOnSelection(indexPath)
        }
    }
```

But when i set  `currentModel.isEnlarged = true` it has no effect, it actually store `false` value, which i notice when debugging. Why?

Comment: @matt im sorry but i fixed issue changing struct to class in CellModel and then i was curious why structs not work and paste it.

Comment: Good, the question makes sense now that you’ve changed it back to struct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
var currentModel = model.models[indexPath.row]
```

If `models` is an array of a struct, `currentModel` is a copy, so setting a property of `currentModel` does not affect anything in the array.

Comment: Might want to read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366050/341994 And my book http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECreferenceTypes

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your code to this as you are saving the new value in a copy of you main model.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var currentModel = model.models[indexPath.row]
        if !currentModel.isEnlarged {
            print("should enlarge")
            model.models[indexPath.row].isEnlarged = true
            enlargeOnSelection(indexPath)
        }   else {
            print("should restore")
            model.models[indexPath.row].isEnlarged = false
            restoreOnSelection(indexPath)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

after changing the value you need to update your array. Since struct is Pass by Value not reference .

```
currentModel = model.models[indexPath.row]
currentModel.isEnlarged = true
model.models[indexPath.row] = currentModel
```

Be careful to check index is available before adding.