# How does = Operator Memory Allocate?

Tags: swift, memory

I have my initial variable.

```
let videoImage:CIImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
```

I create another buffer likeso.

```
let newImage:CIImage = self.videoImage
```

I print them out to look at their memory address

```
print(videoImage)
print(newImage)
```

**Output:**

```
Optional(<CIImage: 0x280b91260 extent [0 0 1128 1504]>
  affine [1 0 0 -1 0 1504] extent=[0 0 1128 1504]
    colormatch "QuickTime 'nclc' Video (1,1,6)"_to_workingspace extent=[0 0 1128 1504]
      IOSurface 0x28073d990(675) seed:47 BGRA8 extent=[0 0 1128 1504]
)
<CIImage: 0x280b91260 extent [0 0 1128 1504]>
```

It seems that they have the same memory address. 0x280b91260

Is there a way to create a new variable with the same exact information but with a different memory address?

For example

```
Optional(<CIImage: 0x280b91260 extent [0 0 1128 1504]>
  affine [1 0 0 -1 0 1504] extent=[0 0 1128 1504]
    colormatch "QuickTime 'nclc' Video (1,1,6)"_to_workingspace extent=[0 0 1128 1504]
      IOSurface 0x28073d990(675) seed:47 BGRA8 extent=[0 0 1128 1504]
)
<CIImage: 0x361a92348 extent [0 0 1128 1504]>
```

Where the first and second are a copy but the first has a memory address `0x280b91260` and the second `0x361a92348` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CIImage is a *class*. A class is a reference type. Assignment of a class instance simply assigns the value of the *pointer*. To put it another way, assignment simply gives two pointers to the same object (your `0x280b91260`). That is what a reference type *is*. See [Is Swift Pass By Value or Pass By Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364117/is-swift-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference/27366050#27366050).

If you want a copy, say `self.videoImage.copy()`.

Comment: Ah. Intriguing. That would also make sense.

Comment: So what is the difference between `videoImage.copy()` and `= videoImage`? Or do they return the same thing?

Comment: All the difference in the world. The copy makes a second CIImage _object_.

Comment: Ahh so the assignment operator provides another pointer to the same object while `.copy()` provides a whole new object with a whole new memory address? Fantastic. What I needed to know. Thanks!

Comment: This is all the difference in the world. I didn't realize. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that you'll have to cast down to CIImage, because `copy()` returns an Any.