# Swift adding object to array appends a copy instead of a reference?

Tags: swift

Sample code:

```
struct test {
    var itest: Int?;
}

var tests : [test] = [];

var t = test();

tests.append(t)

t.itest = 99;

print(tests[0].itest)
print(t.itest)
```

produces

```
nil
Optional(99)
```

So it seems the append command creates a copy of t and not its reference.
If the array would contain a reference of t, both print outs must be itest=99.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Swift Pass By Value or Pass By Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364117/is-swift-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference)

Comment: In Swift only classes are reference types. structs are value types.

Answer (score 2):

A struct is not an "object" in the way you are probably thinking. It's a value. When you assign a value, it's copied. That's by design.

Comment: Thx for clarification