# Swift: Why can't I chain mutating functions after init()?

Tags: swift, initialization, mutable, chain

Why can't I modify an initialized value-type immediately after its initialization?!

```swift
// using swift 5.5
struct Foo {
    var x: Int = 0
    mutating func add(_ y: Int) -> Foo {
        x += y
        return self
    }
}

var thisFails = Foo().add(42)   // ERROR! "Cannot mutate member on immutable value"
var alsoFails = (Foo().add(42)) // Same error

// test 1:
var test1 = Foo()
test1 = test1.add(13)   // Modifying 'test1' and assigning 'test1' is OKAY

// test 2:
_ = Foo()   // Creating something not assigned to variable is OKAY (but pointless)

// test 3:
extension Foo: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { "Weird \(x)" }
}
print("Test3: \(Foo())") // Creating something not assigned to variable is OKAY
```

Why is the statement `Foo().add(42)` problematic?

1. Save some space on the stack (for a `Foo`) and initialize it (like is in test#3);
2. Use it for function `add(_)`;
3. Take the returned value from `add(_)` and assign to variable;

Unless I've missed something from [Swift's Initialization documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html), I don't understand why this fails.

Comment: Why don't  you simply add the proper initializer? That's what they are meant for. `let foo = Foo(x: 42)`. Btw why would you need to return anything if your intent is to mutate at first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Foo is a struct and a struct is a [*value type*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366050/341994). This means that you cannot really mutate a Foo in place; you have to *replace* one Foo with another. When you call `add` on a Foo, you actually get a *different* Foo (with a different `x`) and you replace the old one with the new one. This allows you to do that:

```
var test1 = Foo()
test1 = test1.add(13) // okay too
test1.add(14) // okay too
```

That's fine, because all along we have a shoebox, `test1`, and we can *assign into it* (`var`), which is what is required in order to mutate a struct. `test1` holds a Foo, and when we "mutate" it by saying `add`, we throw away that Foo and put a different Foo in its place.

Its *place*.

But `Foo().add(13)` gives us *nothing to assign into* so you can't say it. It's incoherent. There is no "place" to put the new Foo.

Comment: Even by “throwing away” the old Foo and replacing it.   If `Foo()` gives a Foo, and `add()` produces a completely new Foo…. Then, with that logic, ‘Foo().add()` should work.  Why bother assigning ‘Foo()’ to a shoebox if we know we’ll be replacing it with a different Foo by the following call?

Comment: Simply by existing, Foo exists somewhere in memory, whether it has a named shoebox or not.  So I don't see why assigning it a name before or after a mutation changes anything...  after all, we can use no-name shoeboxes (like my print example).

Comment: I am not here to debate the metaphysics of how _some_ computer language _might_ work, but to help you think productively about the _reality_ of how the Swift language _does_ work.