# Save and Retrieve UIView as NSData in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uiview, nsdata

I am indeting to save a uiview in one view and call it in another view (to save it as PDF)

Anyone knows how can I save and retrieve UIView as NSData in Swift?

Comment: "uiview nsdata swift" in Google gives thousands of results... Searching in SO's search box will also give you good answers to this already answered question.

Comment: @EricD : Can you suggest me a good answer?!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can UIView be copied?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425939/can-uiview-be-copied)

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425939/can-uiview-be-copied), you could try this :

```
let yourViewToData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(yourView)
if let yourViewFromData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(yourViewToData) as? UIView {
  // Do what you want with your view
}
```

Comment: If a question is a duplicate of another one, then *flag the question as a duplicate* instead of answering. If you can't flag or don't want to, then make a comment under the question to give the link to the answer. In any case, please avoid answering with the content of an existing answer. Thanks.